# Not able to create a custom Tiny Core Linux ISO image

Tags: linux, iso

I'm trying to create a custom version of Tiny Core Linux. I extracted the ISO image, added the required tcz files, and made a new ISO, but VMWare Virtual Machine was not able to boot from it. So I just extracted the ISO, recreated it without any changes, and it still didn't get detected by the VM. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you did, and exactly what vmware's error message was. I didn't find any obvious links to how to build your own ISO at the [homepage](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux), but it isn't the way they recommend to add extensions.

Comment: The boot was not able to detect the os. It said operating system was not found. Even if i dint add the extensions, i actually just extracted and formed the iso back but VM was still not able to detect the Os

Comment: Probably the ISO rebuild left out the machinery to boot. That's why you should rummage around the sites for the distribution, and find out how a custom ISO is suposed to be built. The [Fedora instructions](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_Fedora_Live_CD) are extensive, but only applicable to Fedora. Perhaps a minimal Fedora installation works for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ISOLINUX](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/ISOLINUX). It gives you a new ISO image without tampering with your existing one, so your boot configurations will be unchanged.

Comment: OP requires quite a bit more guidance than that, as it seems.

Comment: could u be more specific on what you meant?